# Обнуляется html файл с кодом сайта, когда в него заходишь в браузере. Python

Tags: html, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

1. Мне нужна полная копия страницы для дальнейшего парсинга, но при открытии html файла сама страница держится всего пару секунд, как это обойти
2. Как обойти ошибку 403 при get запросе этого сайта https://www.vseinstrumenti.ru

Код:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

url= "https://www.sdvor.com/tmn/category/perforatory-6114"
UserAgent().chrome

req = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': UserAgent().chrome})
scrap = req.text
print(scrap)
```

> Изначально сохранялся пустой файл, но потом добавил в след строку encoding="utf-8-sig
> и информация файла стала держаться пару секунд

```
with open("index.html", "w", encoding="utf-8-sig") as file:
    file.write(scrap)

soup = BeautifulSoup (scrap, "lxml")
print(soup)
```

Comment: "при открытии html файла сама страница держится всего пару секунд" в браузере. И как это может повлиять на ваш парсинг? ни как не влияет, requests это вам не браузер..  'Как обойти ошибку 403' у меня 200. Могу предположить  что вас блокируют со стороны сайта за частые запросы. "Мне нужна полная копия страницы для дальнейшего парсинга" через селенимум можно получить "полную копию страницы" в том виде которая вам нужна.

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

url = "https://www.sdvor.com/tmn/category/perforatory-6114"
req = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': UserAgent().chrome})
print(req)
# Response [200]
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml")
print(soup.find('a', class_="product-name").text)
#  Перфоратор Makita HR2470
```

Есть доступ к исходникам сайта, можно вытянут нужную инфу.